# angularJS using TypeScript the difference between the following methods

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Could please explain the difference between two methods to load your controllers,service.... etc

```
     var appModule = angular.module("myApp", []);

    appModule.controller("MyController", ["$scope", ($scope)
      => new Application.Controllers.MyController($scope)]);
```

---

```
 module todos {
      'use strict';

  var todomvc = angular.module('todomvc', [])
        .controller('todoCtrl', TodoCtrl)
        .directive('todoBlur', todoBlur)
        .directive('todoFocus', todoFocus)
        .service('todoStorage', TodoStorage);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The first method does dependency injection inline. The second method depends on $inject/constructor argument being setup properly in the controller.

Suggestion : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E&hd=1

Comment: i tried it...what i was trying to achieve is having the controller in  acontroller.ts  and the above declaration in the app.ts

Comment: @samrodrigues method 2 does that. That is what I show in the video as well